# Почему File Uploader не работает на appengine?

Tags: gwt, java, google-app-engine

Использую связку FormPanel + FileUpload (пакет com.google.gwt.user.client.ui). Код нормально работает локально, но при деплое на app-engine не работает вообще. В чем проблема?

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);  
VerticalPanel holder = new VerticalPanel();

FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
upload.setName("upload");
holder.add(upload);       
holder.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(Widget sender)
    {
       form.submit();
    }
}));

form.add(holder);
form.setAction("url");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас отключена оплата (billing) вашего приложения. В этом случае загрузка файлов недоступна. Как включить и пользоваться написано [здесь](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/appengine/docs/billing.html).

Answer (score 2):

Время запроса на GAE ограничена 30 секундами, по-моему, это во-первых.
Во-вторых, GAE не поддерживает запись в файловую систему и класс java.io.File, от которого зависит библиотека FileUpload, не находится в GAE Whitelist. Даже в статье Will it play on GAE FileUpload заявлена как Semi-Compatible:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava.
Вообще для загрузки файлов в GAE предусмотрена Blobstore API:
http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html

Для комфортной загрузки файлов лучше использовать такую форму, с ее помощью можно грузить файлы до 2 Гб, по-моему, неограниченное количество времени:

```
<body>
    <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Короче, в описании Blobstore API все написано.

Answer (score 0):

Если оплата включена, то может быть вы не присылаете верный код ошибки? Локально gae-сервер позволяет идентифицировать конец загрузки с любым статусом, в т.ч. 200 и 204. Правила Google App Engine же требуют заканчивать uploading только кодами 301, 302 и 303. То есть если загрузка прошла успешно, сервер должен возвращать код 302. Для этого можно исправить серверную часть кода, дописав в конце обработки загрузки например такое:

```
response.sendRedirect("random url")
```

Comment: если gae-сервер присылает неверный код, то на загрузку это не влияет. просто не присылается submit complete event!

Comment: Точнее вот так: response.sendRedirect("/")